# Flask url_for doesn't compose correct url under docker/docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Flask app running inside a Docker container running under a swarm. When I use `url_for` to create an external url for the API, it returns the docker service name rather than the absolute path.

Ex.

```py
endpoint = url_for('api_v1.get_me_the_data', sn=123, 
                _external=True, _scheme="https")
```

returns something like `https://app-primary:8000/api/v1/devices/123`.

Other details:

- running using Gunicorn behind an Nginx reverse proxy

I've tried playing with the `SERVER_NAME`, but no dice. Is there an easy way to fix this? Or should I write a wrapper function for `url_for`?

Comment: How was your attempt with `SERVER_NAME` ? was it equal to the actual domain name ? was it inside flask config ?

Comment: Inside the flask config, as "localhost:5000" when running locally

Comment: I don't see an issue with having the docker service name in the url as long as you are behind nginx, unless you mean that nginx is remote not in a container within the same network

Comment: Yea, it works great for internal routing, but it's not terribly useful to return this as a url to a customer as a response from an API. Basically, for paginating results, I return the next and prev url's, but they're not going to be too happy with this result, they need the `app-primary` to be converted to the actual domain. I can write a wrapper function, but was wondering if this is a common issue for people...

Comment: I see, So if you make it something like this `current_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'` and keeping `external true`, it wont work, right ? note that it should be before creating  context

Comment: It started up, but threw 404's for everything (at least it rendered the 404 correctly..?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the python application inside a container and also behind Nginx, then you might need to go with [ProxyFix](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix), it will do two things:

- Getting the Client IP instead of nginx container IP by reading `REMOTE_ADDR`
- Setting the Hostname by reading `HTTP_HOST`

Next you need to make sure that nginx sends these Headers:

```
proxy_set_header Host            $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I'm serving flask app with uwsgi, talking to nginx in another container. My password reset func was sending out links with the container name instead of domain name.
Tried with test_request_contest and 'SERVER_NAME' config variable but failed miserably. The link was still with localhost.
What finally worked for me is a quick and (very) dirty method:

```
def create_external_link(link):
    # splits after 'http(s)'
    linkParts = link.split("//")
    linkLeft = linkParts[0]
    linkRight = linkParts[1]
    # from the right part (after 'http://') take whats after 'containerName/' doing only one split
    linkRight = linkRight.split("/",1)[1]
    fullLink = linkLeft + '//example.com/' + linkRight
    return fullLink
```

and then when creating a link and before passing it further to, for example, mail template:

```
link = create_external_link(url_for('blueprint.endpoint', **kwargs, _external=True))
```

Please use a better solution as soon as you find it, this is an ugly hack.